# Keep getting error when adding days to wp get_the_date()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make something that will light up red if a post is over 2 days old, and green if it is under two days. In order to do this I am trying to add 2 days to the date that the post was made, and then make an if statement in the style="" that will compare the current date to the expiration date. Here is the code I am using to add 2 days to the post date, but it won't print anything that is below it. When I take out "date_add($expire_date, DateInterval('2 days'));" it runs again but it doesn't add the two days. I need it to be in F j, Y because thats how I want it displayed on the site.

```
<?php  
$current_date = date( 'F j, Y' );
$expire_date = get_the_date( 'F j, Y' );
date_add($expire_date, DateInterval('2 days'));
?>
```

Here is the code that I am using to compare $expire_date to $current_date:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: <?php if( $expire_date > $current_date ) { echo( 'green' ); } else { echo( 'red' ); }?>;">
```

Comment: If it doesn't print anything after the code, including errors, then you don't have error reporting on. Try putting `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your `wp-config.php` file. Then you will see errors and better understand what you are doing wrong. Without error reporting, it just turns into a guessing game.

Comment: Thanks! I got this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function DateInterval()

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm not super sure, but looking at the [documentation for `date_add`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php), it looks like they use  the `date_interval_create_from_date_string()` function in their examples. Maybe try that instead of `DateInterval`?

Comment: ... or, you might have to use `new DateInterval('2 days')` instead of just `DateInterval('2 days')`. Since you are passing in an object of `DateInterval` and the way to create objects in PHP is to use the `new` keyword.